# How to change the zoom where the markers are clustered in gmaps4rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-maps, gmaps4rails, markerclusterer

I have this test application, where I am using **gmaps4rails** awesome gem. I am trying to cluster my markers and to do so I do this:

```
<%= gmaps("markers" => {"data" => @markers,"options" => {"custom_infowindow_class" => "yellow", "do_clustering" => true}}) %>
```

I have tried to play with the `clusterer_maxZoom` option, but that doesn't help to achieve what I want.

Right now, you have to zoom out a lot in order to make the cluster image to appear, and I was wondering how can you make that cluster picture to appear before you have zoom out specific X. How can you modify that?

You can see what I mean here: [Clusterer example](http://gentle-cloud-4082.herokuapp.com/maps)

Comment: Checked out your example and yes indeed, that requires some drastic zooming before the cluster appears. Are you using `MarkerClusterer` or `MarkerClustererPlus`?

Comment: Actually I am using the gmaps4rails library, which has support for clustering: https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails

Comment: I know :) But do you know what clustering library `gmap4rails` is using? The `MarkerClustererPlus` library offers more options than `MarkerClusterer`, so it will give you more options to set up how the clustering behaves. Knowing which clustering library is in use will lead to a better answer to your question.

Comment: marker clusterer plus is used: https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails/blob/master/lib/gmaps4rails/view_helper.rb#L73

Comment: I have the same problem, anyone managed  to find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

You could try setting the `maxZoom` and `gridSize` properties of `clusterer` in the Javascript.

For example:

```
var handler = Gmaps.build('Google', { markers: { clusterer: { maxZoom: 16, gridSize: 40 }}});
```